# ¿Puedo usar una library que solo afecte una parte del proyecto?

Tags: html, css

tengo un proyecto bastante avanzado y quería incluir un carrusel. Lo hice con una librería que se llama Materialize. Pude hacer todo y funciona bien, el problema es que para poder usar Materialize tuve que copiar en el head esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Y eso ahora me modificó el estilo de todo el proyecto.

Saben si existe alguna forma de que no me modifique todo? O sea, que solo afecte el estilo del carrusel.
Gracias.

Comment: Puede que haya una forma. Solo vasta saber cuál está primero, y cual último. Pon tu materialize antes de de tu estilo principal, y prueba el resultado

Comment: Puedes buscar opciones en google y encontrarás algo como [esto](https://medium.com/@marcusmichaels/how-to-build-a-carousel-from-scratch-in-vanilla-js-9a096d3b98c9)

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Gracias, ya intenté de muchas formas, y no hubo caso. Siempre intentado poner el estilo de Materialize primero y después el resto de los estilos que tengo en el proyecto, pero mientras está ese link, me modifica todo. Así que ya probaré otro método. Saludos.

Comment: @Triby GRacias por la opción. Ya había probado con otro carrusel que vi en youtube, y tampoco lo pude hacer. O mejor dicho, lo hice y quedó bastante mal :) Es la primera vez que trabajo con esto, así que es todo ensayo y error por ahora.

Answer (score -1):

Mala idea tener que cargar toda una librería de componentes para darle uso sólo a un componente carrusel, le recomiendo usar el plugin owlcarousel2. Recuerde que CSS es estilos en cascada, así que los últimos estilos cargados pisaran los anteriores.

Comment: Hola, creo que esto queda mas como comentario ya que no respondes con total certeza a la pregunta, y a parte tienes la suficiente reputación para hacer comentarios

Comment: Hola @DavidFloresGarcía, sí ya lo sabía, pero por algún motivo no funciona. Si no puedo crear uno, investigo el plugin. Gracias.